# Reading a directory location from text file and move to that directory in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am new in matlab can you please help me with the following?:

I have a text file named config.txt with the following entries:

## --------------------------------Directories---------------------------

directory1 /media/fpdata/data1/ #data1

directory2 /media/fpdata/data2/ #data2

## ----------------------------------------------------------------------

I would like to get the path for directory1 and change the directory inside my code to that directory.

I was trying the following with "grep":

```
config_file = 'config.txt'; %file with information

[fl, p] = grep('-u','directory1',config_file);

disp(p.result)
```

I got the following:

```
config.txt: directory1 /media/fpdata/data1/ #data1
```

from here I would like just to have the path: /media/fpdata/data1/ and then change to that directory

Maybe `grep()` is not the right way to do that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably load the config file, and use textscan to grab the various columns (assumes no white space in folder paths)

```
fid = fopen('config.txt', 'rb');
contents = textscan(fid, '%s %s %s');

is_directory1 = strcmp(contents{1}, 'directory1');
cd(contents{2}{is_directory1})
```

I probably would *not* use `grep` to do this as that seems a little overkill.

Comment: It work perfect, thanks a lot! I was trying with grep because in IDL the following works quite easy using the unix terminal: ----> spawn, 'grep "directory1" config.txt', data ---> split = str_sep(strcompress(data),' ') ---> data_dir = split(1)